# Как открыть ViewPager2 сразу на нужной странице?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Одна активность вызывает другую активность на которой расположен ViewPager2. Нужно вывести ViewPager2 сразу на определённой странице (например на 10-й). Если я пишу

```
viewPager2.setCurrentItem(10);
```

то он открывает 10 страницу, но при этом видно как он листает предыдущие страницы. Как открыть ViewPager2 сразу на нужной странице?

Comment: @ Cypher Да, работает как нужно. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `viewPager2.setCurrentItem(10, false)`.

Второй параметр как раз отвечает за то нужна прокрутка или нет.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59827597/8389574